# SQLAlchemy MySQL complex ORDER BY

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, sql-order-by, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 2 models:

```
class Actor(db.Model):
    ...
    edited_at = db.Column(db.DateTime)

class Publication(db.Model):
    ...
    published_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now)
    actor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('actor.id'))
```

And I need to order actors by either actor.edited_at or publication.published_at field (latest date has priority). Not sure if I can accomplish that in SQLAlchemy or I need to use raw SQL (raw SQL query would be a solution too, btw).

What I have now:

```
(db.session.query(models.Actor, func.max(models.Publication.published_at).label('latest')).join(models.Publication).group_by(models.Actor).order_by('latest desc', Actor.edited_at.desc())).all()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [CASE expression](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case) to choose what to order by, though that's not particularly index friendly:

```
from sqlalchemy import case

latest = func.max(models.Publication.published_at)

db.session.query(
        models.Actor,
        latest.label('latest')).\
    join(models.Publication).\
    group_by(models.Actor).\
    order_by(case(
        [(latest > models.Actor.edited_at, latest)],
        else_=models.Actor.edited_at).desc()).\
    all()
```

Alternatively you could use [`GREATEST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest):

```
order_by(func.greatest(latest, models.Actor.edited_at).desc())
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I've tried case statement, but I didn't guess to use latest variable outside query. Thanks!

Comment: A late addition, but entirely overlooked using [`GREATEST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest), which could replace the more verbose CASE expression.